# Spring Security with basic authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, authentication

I'm using Spring to secure my Rest API and to deal with the authentication I've chosen the Basic Authentication method. 
When I test my method, I use to send a header parameter "Authentication : basic login:password".

**This works very well with "GET" method but not with "POST", is it normal ?**

Some Details.

**This test uses a get method --> works correctly:**

```
@Test
public void testListAll() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertNotNull(mockMvc);

    String userName = "user1";
    String userPassword = "user1";
    String userAuthorisation = "Basic " +
            Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((userName + ":" + userPassword).getBytes());

    String response = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/persons")
            .header("Authorization", userAuthorisation))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    Assert.assertFalse(response.isEmpty());

    List persons = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(response, List.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(persons);
    Assert.assertTrue(persons.size() >= 14);
}
```

**... but not this one which is using POST:**

```
@Test
public void shouldCreatePerson() throws Exception {
    String firstName = Tools.generateValidString((int)(Math.random()*100) + 1 );
    String lastName = Tools.generateValidString((int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    String editorName = "user2";
    String editorPassword = "user2";
    String editorAuthorisation = "Basic " +
            Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((editorName +":"+ editorPassword).getBytes());

    String response = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/persons/create")
            .header("Authorization", editorAuthorisation)
            .param("firstName", firstName)
            .param("lastName", lastName)
            .param("isMale", "true"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    Assert.assertFalse(response.isEmpty());

    Person person = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(response, Person.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(person);
    Assert.assertTrue(person.getFirstName().equals(firstName));
    Assert.assertTrue(person.getLastName().equals(lastName));

    person = personRepository.findOne(person.getId());
    Assert.assertNotNull(person);
    personRepository.delete(person.getId());
}
```

**spring security configurations (I'm using H2 embedded database for user details) :**

```
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="classpath:security.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" id="userService"/>
```

**.... and :**

```
<http auto-config="true">
       <http-basic entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
       <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" method="GET" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_EDITOR')" method="POST" />
   </http>

   <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

**The RequestMapping class of the update method**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/persons") 
public class PersonUpdateController {
@Qualifier("personService")
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;
@Qualifier("errorCodeReader")
@Autowired
private ErrorCodeReader codeReader;

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Person createSimplePerson(
        @RequestParam String firstName,
        @RequestParam String lastName,
        @RequestParam boolean isMale
) {
    Person person;
    try {
        if (isMale) {
            person = personService.create(firstName,lastName,Person.MALE);
        }else {
            person = personService.create(firstName,lastName,Person.FEMALE);
        }
        return person;
    } catch (IncorrectGenderException | InvalidPersonNameException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RestException(codeReader.getError("InvalidPersonName"),"Invalid Person Names",
                "First name or last name is invalid");
    }
}
```

}

**the class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint:**

```
@Component( "restAuthenticationEntryPoint" )
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

@Override
public void commence( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                      AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException {
    response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
}
```

}

I receive this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status
```

Expected :200
Actual   :403

By just changing the method from POST to GET, it works correctly (Status 200) !!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide more information. version, configurations ....

Comment: Please provide methods, code, something...just guessnig though you may be missing Content-type eg application/json?

Comment: thanks, I added some details, please tell if you need more.

Comment: And what "does not work" means? What error messages do you get? Please also show the code (or at least the RequestMapping annotations) of the controller methods, which are called.

Comment: I get status 403 --> problem with authentication. I happens also when I don't insert he authentication header. It's looks like Spring is not inserting the header within a POST method !!